# Entity Framework sqlquery pass current date

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, getdate

I want to call a SQL query with joins to Oracle database. For each table in query i need to check a field for SYSDATE

```
SELECT
    per.PERSON_ID
    ...
FROM 
    PERSON_V per
JOIN 
    SALARY sal ON sal.PERSON_ID = per.PERSON_ID 
                  AND sal.EFF_START_DATE <= SYSDATE 
                  AND sal.EFF_END_DATE > SYSDATE
    ...
WHERE 
    per.EFF_START_DATE <= SYSDATE 
    AND per.EFF_END_DATE > SYSDATE
```

In my code I do as below

```
        var sql = @"SELECT
                    per.PERSON_ID
                    ...
                    FROM PERSON_V per
                    JOIN SALARY sal
                        ON sal.PERSON_ID = per.PERSON_ID AND sal.EFF_START_DATE <= GETDATE() AND sal.EFF_END_DATE > GETDATE()
                    ...
                    WHERE per.EFF_START_DATE <= GETDATE() AND perEFF_END_DATE > GETDATE()";
        var oracle_employees = _oracleDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<List<EmployeeDetails>>(sql);
```

I get GETDATE is invalid identifier. I tried with SYSDATE, DateTime.Now, date as string, none of them worked. What is the right way to pass date to the query from code.

Comment: Why are you using a different command text in c# that in Oracle?  The string gets passed to Oracle and should be the same (unless you are using Entity and linq).

Comment: @jdweng I'm using Entity framework, i had build this query through linq first. But the query generated by linq was too large and it takes too much time to execute. That is why i'm using the sql query directly.  The above code works if i remove the Date conditions. When i pass getdate() in the query all i get is GETDATE is Invalid identifier. If i use DateTime.Now then the error will be last month is invalid.

Comment: You need to use FromRawSQL and use same syntax as Oracle uses : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @jdweng i had made a mistake when i tried with SYSDATE. I had given TOP 100 along with query above. I tried SYSDATE now without the TOP keyword and it worked with Context.Database.SqlQuery. The issue was with TOP 100 added to query.

Comment: Does TOP work if you use query in an Oracle Tool?  If so then does it work with FromRawSQL?